# Как прервать выполнение метода с возвращаемым типом?

Tags: java

Как прервать выполнение метода с возвращаемым типом?

```java
static Double plus() throws IOException {
  System.out.println("Введите число:");
  try {
    String f = inc.readLine(); // Вводим число
    if (f.equals("=")) { // Если пользователь ввел "=", выводим результат
      System.out.println(resl);
      // Вот тут мне нужно прервать выполнение.
    }
    // Все что ниже выполниться не должно 
    resl = resl + Double.parseDouble(f);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

    System.out.println("Вы ввели не число, будьте внимательнее!");
    return plus();
  }
  return resl;
}
```

Заранее благодарен вам.

Comment: Зависит от логики работы программы, как вариант бросьте исключение, либо поставьте в указанном месте `return 0.0`. После этого дальнейший код выполняться не будет.

Comment: Если вы пообещали вернуть результат, так и верните его. А во внешней среде уже выводите результат. То есть будет `if (f.equals("=")) { return resl; }`  а где-то в программе будет `System.out.println(plus());`

Comment: Прервать выполнение метода получилось, теперь вопрос, как после этого сразу же, остановить выполнение программы. (return 0.0, даже с ним дальнейший код выполняется)

Comment: Решил проблему вызвав метод System.exit(0) - завершающий работу программы в том месте где он вызван.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызвать оператор `return` с каким-то значением. Или бросить исключение.

А вообще какая-то странная у Вас логика этого метода. Что за значение он должен возвращать и зачем Вам рекурсия? Не лучше ли сделать так?

```java
static Double plus() throws IOException {
  Double res1 = 0.0;
  while (true) {
    System.out.println("Введите число:");
    String f = inc.readLine(); // Вводим число
    if (f.equals("=")) // Если пользователь ввел "=", выводим результат
      return res1;
    try {
      resl = resl + Double.parseDouble(f);
     } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.println("Вы ввели не число, будьте внимательнее!");
    }
  }
}

System.out.println(plus());
```

Comment: рекурсия для того чтобы ввести значение еще раз, этот метод обрабатывает арифмет.действие "+", вы можете ввести равно и получить результат сразу, но если вы ошиблись вводите число заново.

Comment: @АндрейИсенко это я понял. Но посмотрите мой код. Все то-же самое, но без рекурсии. А из рекурсии Вам нужно будет выходить